# how to recurse over singly linked list with a function that takes no parameters

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to recursively loop over a singly linked-list but I have to use a function that takes no parameters and I'm a little confused how to do that. My thought process was that I would just keep passing in the modified list to the function but that's not what the problem asks for. This is the question:

Suppose that you have a singly linked list of ints without header, with the following class definition:

```
class IntList {
    int value;
    IntList next;
}
```

Write a recursive, owned method `l.sumOfList()` which:

1. destructively replaces the value at each node in the list with the sum of the values of the list starting at that point.
2. should return the sum of the values in the original list. For instance, if l is initially the list `[3,2,1]`, and you call `l.sumOfList()` then `l` becomes the list `[6=(3+2+1), 3(=2+1), 1]`.

> I'm just not sure how to write a recursive function with no
>   parameters? Or how to work with a linked list without a header.

Comment: Wow... that is one poorly worded and rather meaningless assignment.  My condolences.  Here's my interpretation. Assume that a list was magically created, it's just a set of nodes hanging in space with no header (in real Java this would get garbage collected).  You have a reference to one arbitrary node, the `l` mentioned in the assignment.  You have to write a method, which will be a member of `IntList`, that overwrites the value in `l` and all subsequent nodes with the sums of all subsequent nodes.  The end condition for recursion will be  `next==null`.

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks, that helps clarify things a bit!

Comment: That said, the question is off-topic according to the site guidelines in the [help] and [ask].  Experiment with writing the code (a `sumOfList` method in `IntList`) and play with it. When you have some code and a specific question, come back and [edit] your post showing what you have done.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep a class variable and use it in your recursive function. Something like;

```
class TraverseInt {
IntList node = start; // start of the linked list

public void traverse() {
    if(node == null)
        return;
    System.out.println(node.value);
    node = node.next;
    traverse();
}
}
```